# Why is my hyperlink only working offline?

Tags: html, css

I did a hotspot login page and now the problem is that my hyperlink to login is not showing up when I upload it to the MikroTik Routerboard. I don't know whats going wrong. Is there some isue with the configuration of the MikroTik or did I do something wrong. This code is basically the MikroTik template with some slight modifications.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>internet hotspot > login</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url("img/background-min.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            color: #737373;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: verdana;
        }

        textarea,
        input,
        select {
            background-color: #FDFBFB;
            border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
            padding: 2px;
            margin: 1px;
            font-size: 8px;
            color: #808080;
        }

        .signInText {
            background-color: white;
            width: 320px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        a,
        a:link,
        a:visited,
        a:active {
            color: #AAAAAA;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        a:hover {
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #c1c1c1;
            color: #AAAAAA;
        }

        img {
            border: none;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 8px;
            color: #7A7A7A;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    $(if chap-id)
    <form name="sendin" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" />
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="https://welcome.gastfreund.net/164404" />
        <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/md5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function doLogin() {
            document.sendin.username.value = document.login.username.value;
            document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5('$(chap-id)' + document.login.password.value + '$(chap-challenge)');
            document.sendin.submit();
            return false;
        }
        //-->
    </script>
    $(endif)

    <div align="center">
        <a href="$(link-login-only)?target=lv&amp;dst=$(link-orig-esc)"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="signInText">
        <table width="100%" style="margin-top: 10%;">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <div class="notice" style="color: #c1c1c1; font-size: 16px">Bitte hier klicken, um sich im Hotspot gratis anzumelden!
                        <br />$(if trial == 'yes'), <a style="color: #FF8080" href="$(link-login-only)?dst=https://welcome.gastfreund.net/164404&amp;username=T-$(mac-esc)">Hier klicken</a>.$(endif)</div>
                    <br />
                    <table width="280" height="280" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <a href="http://www.company.de" target="_blank" style="border: none;"><img src="img/Logo-min.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="mikrotik" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="color: #c1c1c1; font-size: 9px">Powered by Company</div>
                    $(if error)
                    <br />
                    <div style="color: #FF8080; font-size: 9px">$(error)</div>$(endif)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        document.login.username.focus();
        //-->
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is `name="login"`  - your JS is looking for it

Comment: There are more files than this one so probably in one of the other files, I'm only the one how has to setup the images and test it.

Comment: @kardon: This could have different reasons. probably the image for within hyperlink isn't available on the server and just locally on you machine etc. Could you please add a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ajwy8p demo.